# postgresql suddenly stopped working "incomplete startup packet error"

Tags: postgresql, centos, postgresql-8.3

I've searched and read a lot about these kind of errors, but none of them solved my question. Why does this error happens all of a sudden ? could this to be a problem of memory on the server ? (I checked the disk space and ram though like but it didn't seem to have problems related to this)

Postgresql version 8.3
OS CentOs

```
CLST LOG:  incomplete startup packet
CLST LOG:  received fast shutdown request
CLST LOG:  aborting any active transactions
CLST FATAL: terminating connection due to administrator command
CLST LOG: autovacuum launcher shutting down
CLST FATAL: terminating connection due to administrator command (HERE COMES A LOT OF THESE ERROR LIKE 15 times)
CLST LOG:  shut down
CLST FATAL: the database system is shutting down"
CLST LOG: the database system was shut down on 2021-12-29 11:12:00 CLST
CLST LOG: autovacuum launcher started
CLST LOG: Database system is ready to accept connections
```

then it started to work just fine

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: 8.3 is ancient.  Are you sure that that is really the Postgresql version?

Comment: Your messages have a timezone specification, but not the rest of the timestamp.  Why?  It might be helpful to know how far apart they are.

Comment: @jjanes yes that's actually the postgres version, there are some old sistems in a server that are using that database version and they don't want to update it yet

Comment: @jjanes I'm goint to update the post using the timestamps sorry